# executing variable value as a command gives different result than executing directly in the shell

Tags: java, bash, maven, junit

i'm facing a issue with a mvn command i'm building as a variable value, and then executing.

If i execute the command direcly, as the echo of the variable value, it works perfectly. But if i execute the variable value, it gives me an error like one of the parameters is not inside double quotes.

I need to build the command cause the parameters depends on certain variable names that came from other scripts than run these.

These are the commands:

With this one, i store the maven command in a variable with some extra parameters if the $CLOUD value is true:

```
$ export CLOUD=true && export mvn_cmd="mvn clean test --batch-mode $(if [[ "$CLOUD" == "true" ]]; then echo -Ddevice=\"Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime\" -DnetworkLog=true; fi) -Dcucumber.filter.tags=\"@tmsLink=ID-16848\""
```

If i echo the command is perfectly fine:

```
$ echo $mvn_cmd
mvn clean test --batch-mode -Ddevice="Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime" -DnetworkLog=true -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tmsLink=ID-16848"
```

if i run this with:

```
$ $mvn_cmd
...
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "Galaxy". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

But if i copy and paste the output of the variable diretly in the terminal, it runs perfectly:

```
$ mvn clean test --batch-mode -Ddevice="Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime" -DnetworkLog=true -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tmsLink=TUF-16848"
...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ flow ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not suggesting you REALLY do this in your code but what does running `eval "$mvn_cmd"` output (with double quotes around as all shell variables should have unless you have a specific need to remove them, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)? In general, don't store commands in variables, put them in functions. Also, always do what the bash tag you used instructs - `For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting here.`.

Comment: thanks @EdMorton! it works this way with eval

Comment: You're welcome but as I said - don't REALLY do that, use a function.

Comment: You may want to read [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet, mostly because it makes shell parsing even more confusing than it usually is, and it blurs the distinction between data and executable code even more than usual. In this case, depending on e.g. what the device name is, it might wind up executing part of the device name as shell commands... which probably wouldn't be good. Functions and arrays are both much better ways to store commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the problem is

1. You're storing a command in a shell variable instead of a function, and
2. You aren't quoting your shell variable, and
3. You'd have to use `eval` or similar to execute it if quoted properly.

Try this instead (assuming you're using bash):

```
mvn_cmd() {
    local args
    [[ "$CLOUD" == "true" ]] && args='-Ddevice="Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime" -DnetworkLog=true'
    echo mvn clean test --batch-mode ${args?"$args"} -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tmsLink=ID-16848"
}
```

```
$ mvn_cmd
mvn clean test --batch-mode -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@tmsLink=ID-16848
```

```
$ CLOUD='true'
$ mvn_cmd
mvn clean test --batch-mode -Ddevice="Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime" -DnetworkLog=true -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@tmsLink=ID-16848
```

Remove the `echo` when you're done testing it and ready to use it for real.

Comment: Thank you so much! its working perfectly like this. but how do i split the args in multiple lines if there are too much of them for one line? adding "\" at the end is giving me a command not found at the next line

Comment: nevermind i did like "mvn_args="${mvn_args} -Ddevice=\"Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime\" \ -DnetworkLog=true" thanks!